# VSCode Explorer doesn't update Git file change indicators (Modfied/Untracked)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

After committing all modified and untracked files (`nothing to commit, working tree clean`), **VSCode does not update its explorer UI to indicate that the files are no longer modified/untracked**. I have to reload the window to make the outdated `M`, `U` indicators go away.

**Situation**

- My machine (MacOS)

  - The particular problematic git repository --> problem occurs.
  - Clone of a different remote git repository --> problem doesn't occur.
  - Newly initialized git repository on local --> problem occurs.
- Another machine (Windows) --> problem doesn't occur.
- Another machine (MacOS) --> problem doesn't occur.

**Attempt**

- I tried reinstalling VSCode but the problem still remains.

**Environment**

- VSCode: 1.76.2

  - Same settings sync on both "My machine" and "Another machine".
- Git: 2.40.0
- System: MacOS Apple Silicon
- Default settings aside from some execeptions below.

**VSCode settings.json**

```json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "same"
  },
  "prettier.bracketSameLine": true,
  "remote.SSH.connectTimeout": 60,
  "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
    "ubuntu-VirtualBox": "linux"
  },
  "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true,
  "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false,
  "window.zoomLevel": 1
}
```

**Git Configurations**

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.email=blah
user.name=blah
core.editor=code --wait
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
```

Edit 1: included more settings content.
Edit 2: organized question.

Comment: I don't think the issue is part of the configuration files you provided.
VSCode settings that may cause this behaviour are git.optimisticUpdate: false and git.autorefresh: false.
Since you said that this problem is specific to one git repository, but don't specify that repository, It might be hard for people to assist here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I haven't configured any of the settings that you mentioned. I've updated my current situation in the question.

Comment: thanks for showing your various settings files. please cut down the settings shown to just those needed to reproduce the issue (see the instructions on providing a [mre]). since you found that the issue isn't related to settings, that probably means all-default settings can reproduce the issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Just made things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that the path to my working directory included a folder named in Korean. I changed it to English and it works just fine. It had nothing to do with any sort of configurations.

For anyone using other languages, beware of this!